# Удалить все цифры из строки

Tags: python

Вводится строка. Как из нее удалить все цифры?

Вот, к примеру, вводится:

```
112 sadd dfdf 21 dfheif 1223 12
```

Надо, чтобы выводило:

```
sadd dfdf dfheif
```

**Мои мысли:**
мне кажется, надо составить цикл с 0 до длины строки и, проверяя каждый символ на принадлежность к типу int, удалять его или оставлять. Я не знаю, как делать проверку принадлежности, прошу помочь.

Comment: Уточните, как поступить, если цифра не отделена от строки пробелом:

    '112 sad33d dfdf 21'
или

    '112 sadd 22,3 dfdf 21'

Comment: Первая строка входного файла содержит предложение, записанное с помощью латинских символов, цифр и знаков препинания. 

Все непробельные символы, отличные от латинских символов, следует сразу же удалить из текстов.
Это условие

Comment: Исходя из условия задачи, нужно поступить так:

    import re
    print re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z\s]', '', '112 sadd dfdf 21 dfheif 1223 12')

Это выражение удалит все символы, кроме пробельных и латинских букв.
Но результат будет отличным от того, что в стартовом посте, так как останется несколько пробелов между буквами.

Comment: А без "регулярок" это реализовать возможно?

Comment: Конечно, можно.

Comment: Пожалуйста, подскажите, как.

Comment: Вот так, например, вариантов может быть сотни:

    filter(lambda x: x in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ', '112 sadd dfdf 21 dfheif 1223 12')

Answer (score 4):

```
re.sub(r'[^\w\s]+|[\d]+', r'',"112 sadd dfdf 21 dfheif 12,23 12").strip()
```

Удалит все спецсимволы и числа и в конце почистит пробелы по краям строки.

Comment: Спасибо, а что значат эти вещи:

1) re.sub

2)r'\d+', r''

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html в документации все есть.  
re.sub - это типа string.replace только по регуляркам ищет и по регуляркам заменяет (можно строить сложные схемы)  
\d+ - это стандартное правило регулярок - числа ноль и больше раз подряд.

Comment: В вашем случае останутся символы подчеркивания _

Comment: name 're' is not defined
выдает это

Comment: re  это строка, которая поддается обработке.

Answer (score 3):

Регулярное выражение `\d+` находит цифры. `re.sub()` функцию можно использовать, чтобы удалить все цифры из строки, включая Юникод:

```
import re

s = u"standard digits: 123; unicode: \uff11\uff12\uff13."
s = re.sub(r"\d+", "", s, flags=re.UNICODE)
# -> standard digits: ; unicode: .
```

`bytes.translate()` -- это эффективный метод по удалению набора байт (стандартных цифр в данном случае) из строки:

```
s = b"standard digits: 123;"
s = s.translate(None, b"0123456789")
# -> standard digits: ;
```

Другие способы, например, используя `set()` со [списками включения или `str.replace()` в цикле (или с `reduce()`)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/437445/23044) более многословны и медленнее.

Answer (score 2):

Без регулярок:

```
str1='112 sadd dfdf 21 dfheif 1223 12'  
str2=''  
for c in str1:  
   if c not in ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'):  
      str2=str2+c
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно еще так

```
for d in '1234567890':
    s=s.replace(d, '')
s.strip(' ')
while s.find('  ') != -1:
    s = s.replace('  ', ' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
S = 'ABC 321 ABC 567ccc'
s = ' '.join([x for x in S if not x.isdigit()])
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать функцию:

```
def del_num(text):
    rtrn = ''
    for i in text:
        if not i.isdigit():
            rtrn += i
    return rtrn
```

Answer (score 0):

### Код

Вот мой код без регулярок:

```py
string = list(input('String: '))
new_string = []

for symbol in string:
    if not symbol.isdigit():
        new_string.append(symbol)

new_string = ''.join(new_string).strip()

print(new_string)
```

---

### Объяснение

1. Вводим строку и преобразовываем список, создаем переменную (список) для новой строки.
2. С помощью цикла `for` убираем все символы цифр из строки, проверив все символы по очереди с помощью `.isdigit()` и в новый список добавляем все "не-цифры".
3. Преобразовываем новый список в строку с помощью `''.join()` (`''` (пустая строка) - разделитель элементов списка).
4. Убираем пробелы по краям с помощью `.strip()`.
5. Выводим новую строку

---

### Пример

```
String: 112 sadd dfdf 21 dfheif 1223 12
sadd dfdf  dfheif

[ Program finished ]
```