# Как найти символы из кортежа ('!',',','?') в строке и удалить их?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть кортеж:

```
a= ('!',',','?')
```

И строка

```
dasd,sadarg!ada
```

Как можно найти символы из кортежа в строке и удалить их?

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так:

```
>>> a=('!',',','?')
>>> s='dasd,sadarg!ada'
>>> ''.join(filter(lambda x: x not in a, s))
'dasdsadargada'
```

или

```
>>> ''.join(x for x in s if x not in a)
'dasdsadargada'
```

И в том и в другом случае не удаляем символы из старой строки, а создаем новую строку, в которую входят только те символы старой строки, которые удовлетворяют условию "символ x не входит в кортеж а" (x not in a).

Comment: Зря вы на такие вопросы отвечаете. Решили задачу за человека, избавили его от мыслительных процессов. Задачу можно было решить, в тупую, при помощи циклов, а вот потом уже думать как это сделать красивее и правильнее.

Comment: @Avernial тут не институт :) каждый сам выбирает как ему учиться. и помощь примером еще никогда не была лишней. Любой вопрос можно решить самостоятельно. По вашей логике тут вообще не нужно отвечать? Или отвечать избирательно? Но зачем вообще отвечать? Есть же доки, дизасемблеры... и вперед :)

Comment: Просто есть вопросы, на которые ответ находится в первом попавшемся учебнике по языку. А то потом приходят на работу выпускники которые без посторонней помощи подстроку в строке найти не могут)

Comment: @Avernial: (почувствуйте иронию) проблема домашних заданий затёрта до дыр на большой SO (резюме: ответ должен быть полноценным и содержать полный рабочий пример кода в не зависимости от усилий автора) и она также [обсуждалась на русской Мета](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/231/23044)

Comment: `filter()` тут совершенно не к месту. Тяжелее для понимания и  медленнее.

Comment: @jfs, по поводу понятности не соглашусь, для меня операция фильтрации более интуитивна, чем list comprehensions.

По поводу скорости - нужно смотреть для каждого случая отдельно. В некритичных по скорости местах подойдет и относительно "медленный" вариант с filter. В критичных - возможно будет иметь смысл писать на C/C++, а не на Python.

Comment: @insolor: списковое включение (listcomp) является более идиоматичным в Питоне. Вы можете использовать всё что угодно в своём личном коде, в публичном коде используйте принятые сообществом идиомы.

Comment: @jfs, шаг влево, шаг вправо от того, что якобы принято сообществом - расстрел?) filter, map, zip - встроенные в язык средства, хотя и пришедшие в него из функциональных языков. Я лично не вижу ничего плохого, в том чтобы писать на Python в любом стиле, в том числе использовать filter. Думаю, я могу использовать (и таки использую) эти средства в любом коде, и в публичном в том числе, и вы мне не запретите). Мне кажется, вы просто превращаете идиоматику в догму.

Comment: @insolor: про "якобы": [вот мнение BDFL](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196). Люди, которые читают ответы к вопросу *"Найти символы из кортежа в строке python"* могут не знать принятых норм, поэтому важно использовать идиоматический код (посмотрите на [мой ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/437445/23044): первый фрагмент `''.join([c for c in text if c not in punct])` и только в самом конце (для особых случаев) приведён вариант с `reduce(lambda text, p: text.replace(p, ''), punct, text)`. Я бы ещё простил `''.join(filterfalse(punct.__contains__, text))` без lambda.

Comment: @jfs, это мнение одного человека. Даже несмотря на то, что это BDFL, это не мнение всего сообщества программистов на Python. У меня тоже есть свое мнение, и оно вполне может отличаться от мнения BDFL и мнения _части_ сообщества Python. Я могу использовать тот же filter как в своем коде, так и в чужом публичном коде, если конечно лидер команды не будет против. Но именно мнение лидера команды, а не мнение какой-то части сообщества Python или конкретно BDFL будет решающим. P.S. можете меня не прощать )

Answer (score 3):

[Best way to strip punctuation from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/265960/4279) показывает как можно удалить пунктуацию, используя разные подходы такие как: регулярные выражения, `str.replace()`, `bytes.translate()`, listcomp/genexpr, а также сравнивает их производительность. Похожий вопрос [Deleting consonants from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29998052/4279) проводит сравнение для Питона 3. [Remove punctuation from Unicode formatted strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11066400/4279) демонстрирует решения с акцентом на не-ascii пунктуацию.

Наиболее простое для понимания решение это использовать genexpr как показано в [ответе @insolor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/437196/23044). Идентичное решение, которое использует [listcomp, является более производительным на CPython](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29998052/4279):

```
punct = ('!',',','?')
no_punct = ''.join([c for c in text if c not in punct])
```

Если входной текст содержит только ascii, то `.translate()` метод [быстрее в 10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/265960/4279)-[20 раз](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29998052/4279):

```
translation_table = dict.fromkeys(map(ord, punct))

def remove_punctuation(text):
    # Python 3.5+ improves performance otherwise use bytes.translate
    return text.translate(translation_table)
```

Чтобы [удалить все возможные Юникодные символы пунктуации из текста](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11066400/4279):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import regex # $ pip install regex

def remove_punctuation(text):
    return regex.sub(r"\p{P}+", "", text)
```

[Производительность решения с `.replace()` ухудшается](https://stackoverflow.com/q/265960/4279) с увеличением длины `punct` и `text` (необходимо сравнение с другими подходами для каждого случая):

```
from functools import reduce

no_punct = reduce(lambda text, p: text.replace(p, ''), punct, text)
```

Для коротких кортежей `.replace()` уступает (незначительно) только `bytes.translate()`.