# Удалить все символы после запятой .replace(",*", "")

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть число, например, 130203,93
Должно получится: 130203

В Экселе это удаляется легким шаблоном найти и заменить: ",*" - удалится запятая и все после нее. Как сделать то же самое в `.replace`?

Пробовал так:

```
.replace(",*" , "")
```

не получилось.

Какой символ в "регулярных" выражениях заменяет * на "все что после"?
Либо как указать в том же реплейсе, чтобы удалялось несколько любых символов, например 2 после запятой и включая запятую?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 10):

Мне помог такой код .split(",")[0]

Как я понял делит строку на две части, и возвращает первый кусок до запятой т.е. [0] . Но вопрос открытый как это сделать в replace :)

Comment: А зачем replace, если и так работает как надо?

Comment: Интересны новые знания - а так конечно не знаю "зачем" и "чем лучше".

Comment: можно передать `maxsplit` параметр, чтобы не разбивать строку без необходимости: `s.split(',', 1)[0]`

Answer (score 5):

Если задача состоит именно в удалении первой запятой и всего что после нее, вот это сработает:

```
s = "abcd1234,5678"
print s[:s.find(',')]
```

Regexp для вашей задачи - наверняка перебор.

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста а почему перебор? Они слишком сложные для понимания новичку или грузят систему? Хотелось бы просто знать этот  грааль аналог звездочки * в экселе :)

Comment: Сложные, вы, например, не смогли сходу его написать, кто-то другой может не понять. А в терминах "найти символ и отрезать все после" вы прекрасно описали задачу сами, осталась реализация. Код для работы с regexp внутри огромен и требует времени на исполнение. Ну и зачем делать сложно, если можно просто?

Comment: Спасибо работает, скажите а почему у вас после  print  нету скобок () - видел такое в видео уроках. У меня такое на винде и в линуксе не прокатывает. Это зависит от версии питона или каких то настроек?

Comment: @Amaroc, да, я по привычке для второго код пишу, в третей версии требуются скобки.

Comment: к моему коду почему то не пристыковался ваш вариант. А вот с split все ок. Пример такой:  money.replace("\xa0" , "").split(",")[0] - тут я еще удаляю некие пробелы в цифрах, а потом уже запятые.

Comment: @Amaroc странно. Вариант со split мне нравится даже больше, хотя find может чуть быстрее будет.

Comment: [`s[:s.find(',')]` может молча данные испортить](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/504848/23044), если запятой в строке нет.

Answer (score 4):

Подключаем модуль для работы с регулярными выражениями:

```
import re
```

Заменяем:

```
MyString = re.sub(r',\d+', '', MyString)
```

Регулярку задаём без открывающего и закрывающего слеша, но с `r` перед строкой. Второй аргумент - строка (не регулярка!), которой заменить. Данная регулярка отсечёт все цифры после запятой, вместе с ней. Другие символы будут проигнорированы, однако для работы со строковыми представлениями чисел этого достаточно.

А `.replace`, теперь (не знаю, как раньше), не работает с регулярными выражениями, - только с простыми строками.

Подробнее про модуль `re` [тут](https://tproger.ru/translations/regular-expression-python/).

Comment: вопрос просит удалить *все* символы, а не только цифры (`\d`) после запятой.

Comment: @jfs в начале вопроса очень чётко указаны исходные данные: есть **число**. В числе никаких других символов, кроме цифр, после запятой быть не может, иначе это уже **строка**.

Answer (score 3):

Если имеется число в строковом представлении формата "12345.123", то чтобы отбросить цифры после запятой, достаточно 
`int(float("12345.123")) = 12345`

Comment: Вопрос поставлен так, что требуется преобразовать число

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь floor() из модуля math.

```
math.floor(130203.93)
```

Comment: спасибо но речь не об округлении (как я понял), а именно о приведении данных в тот вид который подойдет как для экселя так и для гугл спредшится (на сколько помню один кушает запятые а другой точки - что не может не раздражать), поэтому по привычки от запятых и точек в "деньгах" стараюсь избавлятся. Это в частном случае - а в общем интересно узнать именно спецсимвол который обозначает "всё после этого" в экселе это *, а в питоне?

Comment: @Amaroc: `math.floor(f)` не округляет. Эта функция возвращает наибольшее целое число меньше либо равное `f` (отличается от `int(f)`). Это было бы возможным ответом, если бы на входе у вас были числа с плавающей точкой, а не строки.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы удалить все символы после первой запятой, включая саму запятую, из строки:

```
s = 'a,b,c'
before_comma = s.partition(',')[0]
# -> 'a'
```

Все(!) ответы, приведённые на данный момент, кроме [`s.split(',', 1)[0]`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/502595/23044) не справляются с этой простой задачей, например:

- [`s[:s.find(',')]`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/502586/23044) может *молча* вернуть неправильный ответ, если в строке нет запятых. Правильное решение должно обрабатывать случай `s.find(',') == -1`, то есть когда `',' not in s`:

  ```
  i = s.find(',')
  before_comma = s[:i] if i != -1 else s
  ```
- [`re.sub(r',\d+', '', MyString)`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/502603/23044) удаляет запятые, которыми следуют цифры, оставляя все остальные символы. Чтобы удалить *все* символы после запятой, используя регулярное выражение:

  ```
  import re

  before_comma = re.sub(',.*', '', s, flags=re.DOTALL)
  ```

  то есть аналогом `",*"` шаблона является `',.*'` регулярное выражение.

Чтобы удалить произвольную пунктуацию, можно использовать `r"\p{P}+"` regex: [Как найти символы из кортежа ('!',',','?') в строке и удалить их?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/437188/23044)

---

Если входные данные в Excel, то следует убедиться что числа с плавающей точкой экспортируются в csv, используя точку, а не запятую в качестве разделителя — это может помочь правильно округлить результат, если данные рассматриваются как числа, а не строки. Или можно использовать библиотеки,  которые позволяют работать с Еxcel файлами (например: `xlrd`, `openpyxl`) или [самим Excel напрямую](https://stackoverflow.com/q/441758/4279).

Comment: Tactical DownVoting - приём, работающий в обе стороны.

Comment: @Risto: я не использую "Tactical DownVoting" (чтобы это не значило). Я минусую ответ, если мне ответ не нравится **и** автор отказывается его улучшить (мне всё равно кто автор, если ответ нормальный).

Comment: Поэтому вам, совершенно случайно, "не понравились" все ответы, с рейтингом выше вашего?

Comment: @Risto: ваше предположение, что я проголосовал "против" всех *" ответ[ов], с рейтингом выше вашего"*, не верно.

Comment: @Risto: любой пользователь с 1000+ репутацией ([позволяет смотреть детали голосования](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user)) может убедиться в правдивости моего комментария. Если вы не знали об этом, то я жду извинений за ложные обвинения в мой адрес.

Comment: "Все(!) ответы, приведённые на данный момент, кроме s.split(',', 1)[0] не справляются с этой простой задачей" - ваши слова.

Comment: @Risto какое это имеет отношение к вашему обвинению что я занимаюсь "Tactical DonVoting". Вы намекаете, что я заминусовал "все ответы, с рейтингом выше вашего". Легко доказать что это ложь. У Вас репутация больше 1000, вы сами можете в этом убедиться. Если следующие слова не являются извинением с Вашей стороны, то можете не отвечать.

Comment: Если человек приходит вопрос, на который уже есть самоответ, и публикует свой, в котором рассказывает, какие все отвечающие, кроме автора, вопроса, дураки, - искомая им выгода очевидна. Ставили вы минусы, собирались поставить, или поставили , а потом передумали - меня не интересует, тем более, что проверить можно только первый вариант.

Comment: Кстати, ответ Динара давно исправлен, а ваш минус там так и висит. Извинитесь перед ним, что ли.

Comment: @Risto "ваш минус" — очередная ложь. Хватит мусорить в комментариях.

Answer (score 2):

Если Вам необходимо работать именно с числами, то для отсечения дробной части можно использовать функцию trunc из модуля math.

```
import math
math.trunc(123.456)
math.trunc(789)
```