# Как удалить пробел, после символа ; в python

Tags: python

есть строка:

```
1111; CD_COUNTRY_2; DE; DE; Германия; ГЕРМАНИЯ; 523; ; ГЕРМАНИЯ ; ; ;
```

Как удалить пробел после символа`;`

Comment: А вы сами пробовали что-то сделать? И если да, то что не получилось?

Comment: думаю ответ на этот ворпос вам поможет http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/502573/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-replace

Comment: Я уже смотрел, там речь идет об удалении всех символов, после запятой.

Comment: `re.sub('\;\s+',';', my_string)` - удалит любое к-во пробелов после `;`

Comment: То что нужно! Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
import re

In [32]: s
Out[32]: '1111; CD_COUNTRY_2; DE; DE; Германия; ГЕРМАНИЯ; 523; ; ГЕРМАНИЯ ; ; ; '

In [33]: re.sub('\;\s+',';', s)
Out[33]: '1111;CD_COUNTRY_2;DE;DE;Германия;ГЕРМАНИЯ;523;;ГЕРМАНИЯ ;;;'
```

если вам также надо избавиться от пробелов **перед** `;`:

```
In [37]: re.sub('\s*\;\s*',';', s)
Out[37]: '1111;CD_COUNTRY_2;DE;DE;Германия;ГЕРМАНИЯ;523;;ГЕРМАНИЯ;;;'
```