# Регулярные выражения (объединение условий)

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Дамы и господа, добрый вечер.

У меня есть текст и я хочу из него удалить все ненужные символы, типа "()-\ и т.д.
Для этого пишу `p = re.compile('([а-яА-Я]+)')`. Далее заметил, что в тексте есть инициалы, например А.В. или В. использую `re.compile('[А-Я]\.')`

Но если совместить эти 2 условия, `re.compile('([а-яА-Я]+)([А-Я]\.)')` выдаёт пустой список.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка. Спасибо!

*'Уважаемые представители департамента по работе с просроченной задолженностью банка "..."!\xa0 Я являюсь клиентом вашего банка, имею потребительский кредит. Да, признаю, что \xa0платежи вношу невовремя, но до сегодняшнего дня они внесены. Сейчас есть также просроченный платеж за май, период просрочки- 1 месяц. Причина- смена работы, все сведения о работе я обязательно в банк сообщу. Сегодня половину платежа я внесла, вторую внесу через 5 дней. Проблема в следующем:\xa0 Ваши сотрудники обзванивают моих соседей, кого именно не знаю, но \xa0видела записку вчера, \xa0воткнутую в дверь моей квартиры, с просьбой позвонить Андрею Николаевичу. Я ранее уже с ним беседовала, и объясняла ситуацию по оплате.\xa0 Зачем звонить соседям, когда можно связаться с самим клиентом. Сейчас трудная ситуация с моим телефоном, он в ремонте, и я могу разговаривать после 18.00 с домашнего. Я не думаю, что сотрудникам так трудно позвонить клиенту после 18.00. В моем договоре , в пункте" Способ обмена между кредитором и заемщиком" написаны следующие способы- телефонные переговоры, смс- уведомления, электронная почта, почта РФ, и личный контакт. Там нет ни слова о соседях.\xa0 Андрей Николаевич, мне пояснил, что они могут передавать информацию третьим лицам, но пункт "Условие об уступке кредитором третьим лицам прав(требований) по договору- не содержит инфо о соседях. Значит третьи лица- это коллекторы или другие подобные учреждения. Но , господа, никак не соседи. Хотя А.Н. меня пытался убедить, что передача инфо соседям - это и есть право требования. Что за неграмотность.*

Comment: Ну а где пример текста ? или вам на угад регулярку писать?

Comment: Добавил. Думал, что сам текст необязателен.

Comment: 1- в качестве примера, достаточно короткой строки, которая показывает проблему. К примеру, 
«`re.sub(r'[^ab]', '', 'a-b(b)a.') == 'abba'`, а я хочу `re.sub(pattern, '', 'a-b(b)a.') == 'abba.'` Не работает с `pattern = r'[^ab]\.'` (не убираются символы)» Это исправляется: `r'^[.ab]'` 2- `[А-Яа-я]` это неправильно (семЁн семЁныч).

Comment: @MaxU здравствуйте, такой вопрос, есть ли смысл практиковать сразу две библиотека такие как keras и theano, просто если keras это просто надстройка над theano то зачем он нужен? или обе будут полезны?

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч, упоминаний и вопросов по Keras гораздо больше. Я бы сосредоточился на TensorFlow и Keras...

Comment: @MaxU ясно, учту.

Comment: @MaxU: [Данные по Stack Overflow за 2016/2017](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/09/14/python-growing-quickly/?cb=1) показывают, что трафика TensorFlow вопросы больше по сравнению с Keras создают среди посетителей Python.

Comment: @jfs, спасибо за ссылку!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы добавить буквальную точку `.` в уже существующий набор символов `[а-я]`, просто поместите её внутрь `[]`:

```
'[.а-яА-ЯёЁ]'
```

Этот regex ищет символы русского алфавита и точку. Внутри `[]` не обязательно экранировать `.` мета-символ в регулярном выражении. `[a-я]` не включает `ё` букву. Нормализация текста (NFC, NFKD) может иметь значение. `\p{IsCyrillic}` regex находит и такие кириллические символы как `ⷬ ⷭ ⷮ ⷯ ⷰ ⷱ ⷲ`— посмотрите хотите ли вы их поддерживать в вашем случае.

В общем случае, если вы хотите чтобы нашлось либо A либо B regex, можно использовать:

```
A|B
```

Чтобы произвольные буквы находить (не только на русском), можно `\w` использовать (ищет буквы разных алфавитов, которые могут быть частью слов, цифры, подчёркивание).

Чтобы удалить произвольную пунктуацию из текста, можно использовать `\p{P}` регулярное выражение:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import regex # $ pip install regex

def remove_punctuation(text):
    return regex.sub(r"\p{P}+", "", text)
```

См. этот и другие варианты решения в [Как найти символы из кортежа ('!',',','?') в строке и удалить их?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/437445/23044)

Answer (score 0):

У вас нет разделителя, вот подкорректированный паттерн под ваши требования:

```
pattern = re.compile("([а-яА-Я]\.[а-яА-Я]\.)|([()/\\\-])")
```

Загвоздка в "|" между скобками, у вас его не было, по этому все что шло во вторых скобках воспринималось как продолжение того, что шло в первых.

```
([а-яА-Я]\.[а-яА-Я]\.)
```

Находит аббревиатуры, далее "|" и следующее условие:

```
([()/\\\-])
```

Находит лишние символы.