# Помогите составить регулярное выражение, убрать все символы кроме букв, цифр и символов ? ! ,

Tags: python

К примеру, из строки

> Hello, как дела123?!'':)

Получить просто

> Hello, как дела123?!

Вот находил пример как убрать все символы кроме букв,

```
import re
list(filter(None, re.split('\W|\d', 'Hello, как дела123?!'':) ')))

>>> ['Hello', 'как', 'дела']
```

но не знаю как оставлять цифры и `! ? , .`

Comment: `re.sub(r'[^\w\d+\s,.?!]', '', s)`

Comment: @slippyk \w уже содержит \d. \w содержит _. + лишний

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если ещё можно `_` (подчёркивание) оставить в дополнение к буквам, цифрам и `'!?,.'`:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'Hello, как дела123?_!'':+): )'
>>> re.sub(r'[^!?,.\w]+', '', s)
'Hello,какдела123?_!'
```

```html
<script  src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython.js"></script><script  src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython_stdlib.js"></script><body onload="brython()"><script type="text/python">
import re

from browser import document, html 
@document["mybutton"].bind("click") 
def on_click(event):
    s = document["s"].value
    document <= html.P(re.sub(r'[^!?,.\w]+', '', s))
</script><input id="s" value="Hello, как дела123?_!'':+): )"><button id="mybutton">Почистить строку !</button></body>
```

`re` модуль из стандартной библиотеки не поддерживает `[:alnum:]` POSIX класс ([`str.isalnum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum) аналог). Можно использовать [`regex` модуль с тем же интерфейсом](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/):

```
>>> regex.sub(r'[^!?,.[:alnum:]]+', '', s)
'Hello,какдела123?!'
```

В этом случае `_` удаляется.

---

Есть тонкие отличия в обработке не-ascii цифр:

```
>>> regex.sub(r'[^!?,.[:alnum:]]+', '', 'а_1²3½０１２３４５６７８９я')
'а13я'
>>> regex.sub(r'[^!?,.\w]+', '', 'а_1²3½０１２３４５６７８９я')
'а_13０１２３４５６７８９я'
>>> re.sub(r'[^!?,.\w]+', '', 'а_1²3½０１２３４５６７８９я')
'а_1²3½０１２３４５６７８９я'
```

`[:alnum:]` здесь только ascii цифры распознаёт. `\w` в `re` модуле разрешает не только десятичные цифры, но и [символы из категории digit, numeric, к примеру: `²½`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22793379/4279). `\w` в `regex` разрешает только `Numeric_Type=decimal` цифры ([`str.isdecimal()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdecimal)).

---

Чтобы удалить произвольную пунктуацию из текста, можно использовать `\p{P}` регулярное выражение:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import regex # $ pip install regex

def remove_punctuation(text):
    return regex.sub(r"\p{P}+", "", text)
```

См. этот и другие варианты решения в [Как найти символы из кортежа ('!',',','?') в строке и удалить их?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/437445/23044)