# Необходимо очистить строку от посторонних символов

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, строки

Строка содержит различные символы, нужно удалить все, оставив лишь буквы и пробелы.
Как я понимаю, нужно действовать через регулярные выражения, но как конкретно — мне непонятно.

Comment: похожие вопросы: [Удалить все цифры из строки](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/363427/23044), [Как удалить все пробелы из строки в Python?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/359306/23044)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

При помощи regexp можно так:

```
import re
s = 'Hello!@#!%!#&&!*!#$#%@*+_{ world!'
reg = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z ]')
print(reg.sub('', s))
```

Comment: Все получилось, но команду вводил reg, а не regex, видимоб различие версий сказывается. Спасибо!

Comment: Прошу прощения, это у меня опечатка.

Answer (score 3):

Имеется метод str.translate(), который удаляет все символы из строки, содержащиеся в некотором наборе. regexp тут не нужны скорее всего.

Comment: наткнулся на такую строчку str.translate(None, string.punctuation), но при ее реализации выдает, что метод translate принимает только один аргумент

Comment: А у меня все работает. Без конкретного кода и версии Питона (хотя вряд ли в ней дело) ничем не помочь.

Comment: python 3.4

    import string
    fhand= open('C:\Python34\west.txt')
    intab=string.punctuation
    outtab=None
    trantab=maketrans(intab, outtab)
    for line in fhand:
     line = line.translate(trantab)
     line = line.lower()
     print(line)
    #затем идет работа со строкой(подсчет букв)

Comment: да...с оформлением коммента косяк :(

Comment: Начните с минимального кода, без файлов, punctuation и т.п.

Comment: import string
print(string.punctuation)
str='125262 2622, !!sgsgsh'
l=str.translate(None, string.punctuation)
print(l) #По-прежнему выдает, что translate берет только один аргумент, а я предлагаю два, в случае если без none, то строка не изменяется

Comment: Я еще раз предложу попробовать без punctuation

Comment: создать список символов вручную? ладно, спасибо за совет, буду колупаться дальше :)

Comment: попробовал примеры с regexp и translate. translate работает на много быстрее!!!! Особенно на больших строках

Comment: Еще бы! Не нужно использовать regexp там, где он не нужен.

Comment: @KapustinAlexander: попробуйте входной текст, содержажий не-ascii символы. Юникодная версия `translate()` *гораздо* медленнее. [Пример сравнения производительности разных методов](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29998052/4279)

Comment: @SimonZen: если категории символов, которые необходимо удалить/оставить известны, то автоматически можно список составить, вот [пример с Юникодной пунктуацией (обратите внимание как `unicodedata` используется)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11066687/4279).

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то этот метод переводит строку по буквам в соответствии с таблицей см. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_translate.htm

Answer (score 3):

Если хочется оставить только ascii буквы и соответствующие стандартные символы пробела, то `bytes.translate()` является наиболее эффективным методом:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from string import ascii_letters, whitespace

good_chars = (ascii_letters + whitespace).encode()
junk_chars = bytearray(set(range(0x100)) - set(good_chars))

def clean(text):
    return text.encode('ascii', 'ignore').translate(None, junk_chars).decode()

print(clean('Hello1@#!%!#&&!*!#$#%@*+_{ world!'))
# -> Hello world
```

Если необходимо сохранить произвольные буквы и символы пробела, то можно использовать регулярные выражения:

```
>>> import regex as re # $ pip install regex
>>> print(re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', 'Hello1@#!%!#&&!*!#$#%@*+_{\u00A0ёж!'))
Hello1_ ёж
>>> print(re.sub(r'[^\pL\p{Space}]', '', 'Hello1@#!%!#&&!*!#$#%@*+_{\u00A0ёж!'))
Hello еж
```

Стандартный `re` модуль не поддерживает `\p{}` Юникодные свойства, поэтому необходимо использовать `regex` модуль. Различные классы символов такие как `\w`, `\pL` могут порождать слегка отличные результаты (см. `ёж` vs. `еж` в примере). Можно также использовать Юникодные свойства напрямую: [`unicodedata` + `unicode.translate()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11066687/4279).

Answer (score 2):

Можно replace использовать. Более человеко-понимаемо чем всякие regexp

```
>>> i = 'abcdefg'
>>> i.replace('cde','')
'abfg'
```

Конечно это может быть утомительно и выглядеть слишком громоздко, но куда понятнее, чем regexp - который являет собой ни что иное, как рудимент трудно-читаемого программирования прошлого. Вы ещё перфокарты возьмите и попротыкайте...

```
>>> i = 'a$%b@.c&d*!@e$f%g'
>>> i.replace('%','').replace('$','').replace('@','').replace('*','').replace('.','').replace('!','').replace('&','')
'abcdefg'
```

Comment: А ваша строка похожа на дико корявую лапшу. Тогда уж в цикле делать.

Comment: лучше иметь код из лапши, которую человеческий глаз может прочитать, чем кодировать код regexp-ами которые нужно сидеть и разбирать по пол часа каждый символ. Единственное, почему regexp-ы ещё в моде - это скорость. Как только напишут нормальные методы для таких тривиальных вещей как replace и delete, так ваши regexp-ы уйдут в музеи, акурательно рядом с перфокартами и польской инверсной записью будут стоять.

Comment: я думаю @Avernial имел ввиду: `for junk_char in "%$@*.!&": s = s.replace(junk_char, '')` (for-цикл, а не regex). Что может быть оправдано  для пары-тройки `.replace()` вызовов. Для большего кол-ва, можно `bytes.translate` использовать: [`s = s.translate(None, b"%$@*.!&")`](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/446845/23044)

Answer (score 0):

хотел бы добавить чуток полезного на примере датафрейма!

```
# приводим к нижнему регистру, учитываем наличие в тексте цифр, 
# c которыми не работает метод lower()
data.iloc[:,0] = data.iloc[:,0].apply(lambda x: ''.join([char.lower() if 
    not char.isdigit() and char is not None else char for char in x]))
    data['Text'] = data['Text'].apply(lambda x: x.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)))
    data.iloc[:,0]=data.iloc[:,0].apply(lambda x: re.sub('  ', ' ', x)) # удаление лишних пробелов
    
    import nltk
    nltk.download('stopwords')
    from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
    stopwords.words('russian')
    nltk.download('punkt')
    from pymorphy3 import MorphAnalyzer
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
    
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('russian'))
    data['Text'] = data['Text'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in word_tokenize(x) if word not in stop_words]))
    #Токенизируем
    # Загрузка списка стоп-слов для русского языка
    stopwords_ru = stopwords.words('russian')
    morph = MorphAnalyzer()
    
    def lemmatize_and_tokenize(doc):
        doc = re.sub(r'[^а-яА-Я]', ' ', doc)  # Заменяем не буквенные символы
        tokens = []
        for token in doc.split():
            if token and token not in stopwords_ru:
                token = token.strip()
                token = morph.parse(token)[0].normal_form  # Используем метод parse и normal_form
                tokens.append(token)
        if len(tokens) > 2:
            return tokens
        return tokens
    morph1 = MorphAnalyzer()
    
    def lemmatize(text):
        
        text = re.sub(r'[^а-яА-Я]', ' ', text)  # Заменяем не буквенные символы на пробелы
        clear_text = text.split()
        clear_text = [word for word in clear_text if word not in stop_words and len(word) > 2]
        clear_text = ' '.join(clear_text)
        clear_text = ' '.join([morph1.parse(word)[0].normal_form for word in clear_text.split()])
        return clear_text
    
    data['Text_lemmatized'] = data['Text'].apply(lambda x: lemmatize(x))
    data['Text_tokenized_lemmatized'] = data['Text'].apply(lambda x: lemmatize_and_tokenize(x))
#data_c.to_pickle('df_clear.pkl')
#data = pd.read_pickle('df_clear.pkl')
```