# Как удалить все буквы из элементов списка?

Tags: python

Есть список:

```
Х = ['d1', '2ас', '3а']
```

Нужно удалить все буквы, чтобы получить список такого вида:

```
Х = ['1', '2', '3']
```

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Удалить все цифры из строки](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/363427/23044)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Один из многих вариантов решения - воспользоваться регулярными выражениями:

```
In [109]: X
Out[109]: ['d1', '2ас', '3а']

In [110]: import re

In [112]: XX = [re.sub('\D+', '', i) for i in X]

In [113]: XX
Out[113]: ['1', '2', '3']
```

данное регулярное выражение удалит все "не цифры", т.е. все кроме цифр

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
list(map(lambda x: "".join([i for i in x if i.isdigit()]), ['d1', '2ас', '3а']))
```

Comment: `isdigit()`может больше чем надо разрешить, к примеру верхние/нижние индексы такие как `'²'`. Сравните со `string.digits`, `\d` regex, `unicode.isdecimal()` (оставляя за кадром сомнительную применимость map+lambda по сравнению с простым list comprehension).

Answer (score 0):

```
ords = range(48, 58)
[''.join(i for i in s if ord(i) in ords) for s in X]
```

Comment: Это нечитаемый код (`ord(i) in range(48, 58)` лучше выразить как  `char in string.digits`, или (опционально) для совместимости с `\d` regex, как `char.isdecimal()`).  [Пройдите по цепочке ссылок я наверху дал](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/363427/23044), чтобы посмотреть как разные варианты фильтрования строк могут выглядеть и когда разные варианты предпочтительно использовать.